# Comparison operator misbehaving

Tags: php

Just the other day I was making a function that would pull an XML file from a remote server and upon successful retrieval it would return me a SimpleXMLElement object or return false if it wasn't able to get that information lets say due to network failure.

A common yet lazy practice is to check function responses using an if check to make sure if there was something in the variable.
Possibly the code below will try to better explain what I'm trying to say

```
<?php 


$xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?><root><node>A</node></root>";
$xmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

var_dump($xmlElement);
//Shows an xml element that is not empty 

var_dump((bool)$xmlElement);
//Returns true

if($xmlElement)
{
    //Executions comes inside
    echo "i`m true";
}


var_dump($xmlElement == false);
//Strangely this is also true


?>
```

Can someone explain why the result of comparison operator is **Boolean(true)** ?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, the element is not empty. Even stranger, casting the element to bool results in `true`: https://eval.in/526013

Comment: you're right @jeroen .. strange behavior..

Comment: Actually I tried var_dump((bool)$xmlElement == false) and it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($xmlElement == false)
```

We compare $xmlElement and the value False. So if $xmlElement is False, comparison will be True (false == false). PHP needs to convert $xmlElement into boolean.

PHP doc for booleans :
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - **SimpleXML objects created from empty tags**

Comment: Not my dv but you need to use English

Comment: Yeah sorry about that...

Comment: You should try a `var_dump( (bool) $xmlElement );` just for fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research (http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

This quote is the first comment :

> To further previous comments and drive the point home:
>
> What makes SimpleXMLElement tricky to work with is that it feels and >behaves like an object, but is actually a system RESOURCE,  (specifically a >libxml resource).
>
> That's why you can't store a SimpleXMLElement to $_SESSION or perform >straight comparison operations on node values without first casting them to >some type of object.  $_SESSION expects to store 'an object' and comparison >operators expect to compare 2 'objects' and SimpleXMLElements are not >objects.
>
> When you echo or print a node's value, PHP converts the value (a resource) >into a string object for you.  It's a time saver for sure, but can fool you >into thinking that your SimpleXMLElement is an object.
>
> Hope this helps clarify

So apparently your object is a ressource. My guess is that it's a PHP bug...

```
var_dump((bool) $xmlElement) => bool(True)
var_dump($xmlElement == false) => bool(True) //No reason
var_dump((bool) $xmlElement == false) => bool(False) //Why is behavior different ?
```

Comment: So you're saying typecasting resource to a boolean would give us true if it's not empty in our case var_dump((bool) $xmlElement) => bool(True) but during this statement var_dump($xmlElement == false) when it's trying to do the same it converted to false?

Comment: My guess is that the implicit conversion of $xmlElement is not done correctly, maybe because it is not a real object but a ressource...